# Does the reaction between sulphuric acid and ammonium hydroxide give off heat?

Tags: acid-base

I have a mystery solution lab in chemistry, and I was wondering if the addition of $\ce{H2SO4}$ to $\ce{NH4OH}$ gives off heat? Or is there maybe a precipitate or color change?

Answer (score 1):

$$\ce{2 NH4OH(aq) + H2SO4(aq) -> (NH4)2SO4(aq) + 2 H2O(l)}$$

This is an acid base reaction. $\ce{NH4}$ compounds are always water-soluble, so no precipitate, and no color change will be observed. Neutralization reactions like the one above are generally exothermic (they release heat).

This can be proved by observing their heats of formation:

$$\begin{align}
\Delta H_{\mathrm f(\ce{(NH4)2SO4})} &= \pu{-1181 kJ/mol} \times \pu{1 mol} &&= \pu{-1181 kJ} \\
\Delta H_{\mathrm f(\ce{H2O(l))}} &= \pu{-285.8 kJ/mol} \times \pu{2 mol} &&= \pu{-571.6 kJ} \\
\Delta H_{\mathrm f(\ce{H2SO4})} &= \pu{-909 kJ/mol} \times \pu{1 mol} &&= \pu{-909 kJ} \\
\Delta H_{\mathrm f(\ce{NH4OH})} &= \pu{-80.8 kJ/mol} \times \pu{2 mol} &&= \pu{-161.6 kJ}
\end{align}$$

Thus the $\Delta H_{\text{r}}=(\pu{-1181 kJ} + \pu{-571.6 kJ}) - (\pu{-909 kJ} + \pu{-161.6 kJ}) = \pu{-682 kJ}$ is negative, hence the reaction is exothermic.